# PHP array error

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array called a.

```
$a = array(1=>'one',2=>'two');
```

and another array $b

```
$b = array(a => $a); This doesnt work while,

$b = array(a => array(1=>'one',2=>'two')); works.
```

Comment: `$b = array('a' => $a);` should work; string array keys must be enclosed in quotes

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The first one emits a notice "Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a'", but it works. However, you should use strings (text in quotes ;)), like the others mentioned.

Comment: My bad. It was a case of mismatched quotes in an instance which I failed to notice. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enclose the key in quotes like this:

```
 $b = array('a' => $a);
```

[A key may be either an integer or a string.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) If the key is a string, it must be enclosed in quotes, which your code is missing.

See the fixed code working in action [here](http://codepad.org/PVG5FbLV).

Comment: +1, correct. but specifically, *non-numeric* keys are strings, and must be in quotes. (user already has *numeric* keys working without quotes, which is fine)

Answer (score 3):

Unable to replicate.  Both of your examples "work" for me, in the sense that they produce a data structure of:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [1] => one
            [2] => two
        )

)
```

However, you shouldn't be using `a` as a bareword, i.e. it should be:

```
$b = array('a' => $a);
```

Possibly in your actual code this is causing you trouble; I can't say for sure because your made-up example doesn't actually generate the failure.

Answer (score 1):

just tested it it should work, have a look at the link

http://codepad.org/r86J8WtQ

Answer (score 1):

For debugging always set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. In your case, the reason why it's not working would be displayed.

You have to quote `a` => `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

Though shamittomar is correct that you should enclose your string array indexes with quotes, PHP magically turns undefined constants (your strings without quotes) into strings, which creates a warning but still runs your code. I tried all the examples on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and they worked fine!